# Getting A NullRefrenceException And Cannot Find Out Why?

Tags: vb.net, browser, nullreferenceexception

My goal here is to create a web browser that has a tab system in VB. Since I cannot explicitly name every single new tab the user will use, I have to make more generalized callings. Here's the conflicting code (my btnGo):

```
Dim thisBrowser As newWebBrowser = Me.tabBrowser.SelectedTab.Tag
    If txtAdressSearch.Text.Contains(".com") Or txtAdressSearch.Text.Contains(".net") Or txtAdressSearch.Text.Contains(".gov") Or txtAdressSearch.Text.Contains(".edu") Or txtAdressSearch.Text.Contains(".org") Then 'More to be checked for
        thisBrowser.Navigate(txtAdressSearch.Text)
    Else
        thisBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&rlz=1C1ASAA_enUS445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=" + txtAdressSearch.Text)
    End If
```

And here's the `newWebBrowser` code:

```
Public Class newWebBrowser
Inherits WebBrowser

Private Sub webBrowserComplete() Handles Me.DocumentCompleted
    Dim newTab As TabPage = frmBrowser.Tag()
    Dim frmSK As New frmBrowser
    Dim hi As String
    newTab.Text = Me.DocumentTitle
    frmSK.txtAdressSearch.Text = Me.Url.ToString

End Sub
```

End Class

Any time I enter something into `txtAdressSearch`, Visual Studio raises a NullRefrenceException and highlights `thisBrowser.Navigate(txtAdressSearch.Text)`. As a side note, it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Anyone know whats the problem here? Thank you.

Comment: @DourHighArch, ah, sorry. Just saw the conflicting tags. Its VBA.

Comment: Your browser reference is dependent on there being a Tab selected somewhere and the Tag prop containing a valid object reference.  (and seems more like VB.NET than VBA code)

Comment: @Plutonix, there was always a tab selected. As for the Tag property, I am not 100% sure if it does have an object reference. How would I check this?

Comment: It almost certainly doesnt have a valid object or you would not get the error.  In NET just hold the mouse over `Tag` or `thisBrowser` after the assignment.  See also  [NullReference Exception in Visual Basic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix, when I hover over `thisBrowser`, it says nothing, which is probably the cause of this issue. How would I go about setting the Tag to what I want it to be?

Comment: Nothing in VB means null, so when you do Nothing.Navigate(..) You get a null reference exception.

You should check why thisBrowser doesn't get initialized properly

Comment: @Y.S, thanks, I solved it. I forgot to put in a very big chunk of what I needed to put, so tags weren't lining up correctly with what they were supposed to be. Either way, thanks for taking time to try to help.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging for more than an hour, I looked over my code and saw I was missing a big part of it. I wrote it all in and it worked fine. The issue was the tags weren't being defined correctly (and in some cases, not at all) so `.Tag` was returning `Nothing`.

Thanks to all who helped.